# DBpedia extract information

Tags: ontology, wikipedia, dbpedia, knowledge-graph

I want information about every Person and all the attributes associated to it from the DBpedia database. How do I do that?

I tried searching in the ontology --dev section but couldnt find anything meaningful. I tried using SPARQL as well but it seems not to give appropriate results.